# How to use code from optional subspec in core subspec

Tags: swift, cocoapods, precompile, subspec

Does anyone know of a way to use code from an optional subspec in the core subspec of a pod?

Example:

- optional subspec contains the protocol: `SometimesAvailableProtocol`
- in the core I want to define a variable of that type if it exists, something like:

```
#if canImport(SometimesAvailableProtocol)
    var sometimesAvailableVar: SometimesAvailableProtocol
#endif
```

However, unfortunately `canImport` only works with modules and we have noticed that if you use something like `canImport(MyPod.SometimesAvailableProtocol)` it works or fails randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, you can use:

```
optional_subspec.ios.pod_target_xcconfig = { "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS" => "$(inherited) -D MY_SUBSPEC" }
optional_subspec.tvos.pod_target_xcconfig = { "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS" => "$(inherited) -D MY_SUBSPEC" }
```

and then in the core just do `#if MY_SUBSPEC`

Comment: Important Caveat: The swift flag created by this method is only present within the module defined by the Podspec. Other modules cannot observe the value and do their own conditional instantiation.