# Cocoapods: How to check if class in optional subspec is available?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Say I have a Podspec that defines a `MediaImporter` framework. It has some classes in a `Core` subspec (which is marked as the default subspec) and also includes 2 optional subspecs:

1. MediaVideo
2. MediaPhoto

These subspecs contain various classes specific to importing that kind of media. Let's say one class in `MediaVideo` is called `MediaVideoHandler`. How do I check whether or not I can instantiate that class in my code, based on its inclusion in the project? Subspec files are just added to the module created by the Podspec (MediaImporter), so I can't use `#if canImport(MediaVideoHandler)` because that's a class and not a module and always returns false.

**Note:** I tried the solution in this answer: [How to use code from optional subspec in core subspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74571918/how-to-use-code-from-optional-subspec-in-core-subspec)

I put this in the `MediaVideo` subspec:

```
ss.ios.pod_target_xcconfig = { "OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS" => "$(inherited) -D MEDIA_IMPORTER_MEDIA_VIDEO"}
```

However, only the #else block is ever run. I can see the flag in the Pod project's target for `MediaImporter`.

And then in my code:

```
#if MEDIA_IMPORTER_MEDIA_VIDEO
  // Instantiate `MediaVideo` class
#else
  // Do something else.
#endif
```